# Docker build does not copy single file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a dockerfile that copies entire directory to the image and a single file is not copied. The file is located in a subfolder with 2 other files which do get copied.
there is no .dockerignore.
It is a sqlite db file.

this is the dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
  COPY . App/
  WORKDIR /App
  RUN sed -i 's/TLSv1.2/TLSv1.0/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
  RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/App/entrypoint/entry_script.sh"]
  ENTRYPOINT ["/App/entrypoint/entry_script.sh"]
```

Comment: Why do you think the file isn't copied?

Comment: Please check ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy
The example below uses a relative path, and adds “test.txt” to <WORKDIR>/relativeDir/:

COPY test.txt relativeDir/
Whereas this example uses an absolute path, and adds “test.txt” to /absoluteDir/

COPY test.txt /absoluteDir/

Comment: Are you sure that file is no exists after `COPY` step? Try to `RUN ls -l /App/path/to/file` after `COPY`. Maybe this file is deleted when application runs

Comment: @HansKilian when i enter the container and ls the folder where the file is suppose to be only that file is missing.

Comment: @rzlvmp will try that now

Comment: @markorial Do you have any volume mappings when you run the container? If you map anything on top of the directory the file is in - or any of it's parent directories - the file will be hidden by the mapping,

Comment: finally found the issue for some reason latest was not pulling the right image. Had to manually remove all  versions of the image for it to pull latest.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there is this file .dockerignore
This file tells the docker to exclude specific files or folders to be copied to docker image.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, looking everywhere for a solution.
I use Docker Desktop on Windows with WSL.
While starting (running) my container I had a command failing because one file that was supposed to be copied wasn't there, according to my Docker Desktop logs. However, using Docker Desktop, I could see that the file was at the correct place, with the correct rights.
Turned out that the problem came from my file breakline type.
I created the file on Windows so breakline type was CR+LF while linux require LF. I changed that on notepadd++, I rebuilt the image with the same Dockerfile with the same COPY command and the problem was solved...